# How to keep order of elements in first file when merging two xml files using xstl 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have two XML files which have a header, section and a trailer. The section itself has section header, section details and section trailer. I need to merge the two files at two levels - first at section level and then at section detail level. I want my results to be based on the first file (Headers and trailers will come from the first file). If the section matches, I need to keep the ordering of section details from the first file (there is no sort key for ordering, just the order of occurence). If section is not there in the first file, I need to add the whole section from the second file.

I have the xsl which gives me the results but the ordering is not correct. I need help on how to order them. I did not try key lookup as I was not sure how to account for sections that are not there in the first file. 
When the SectionDetails match, I need the records from first file to appear before the records from second file.

My first file, FileA is here

```
<FileRecord>
    <HeaderRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </HeaderRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Science">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Physics">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Biology">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Math">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Algebra">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Calculus">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <TrailerRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </TrailerRecord>
</FileRecord>
```

The second file FileB is here

```
<FileRecord>
    <HeaderRecord>
        <A>FileB</A>
    </HeaderRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Science">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Math">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="History">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Ancient">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Modern">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <TrailerRecord>
        <A>FileB</A>
    </TrailerRecord>
</FileRecord>
```

And the xsl I am using is here

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xsi xsl"
>
    <xsl:param name="filebrecs" select="document('FileB.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FileRecord"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FileRecord">
        <FileRecord>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderRecord"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="SectionRecord, $filebrecs/FileRecord/SectionRecord" group-by="@Subject">
                <SectionRecord>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Subject"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/> </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/SectionHeader"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()//SectionDetails" group-by="@Stream">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/SectionTrailer"/>
                </SectionRecord>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TrailerRecord"/>
        </FileRecord>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting result like this

```
<FileRecord>
    <HeaderRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </HeaderRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Science">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Physics">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Biology">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="Math">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Algebra">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Calculus">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>
    <SectionRecord Subject="History">
        <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionHeader>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Ancient">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionDetails Stream="Modern">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
        <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
    </SectionRecord>

    <TrailerRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </TrailerRecord>
</FileRecord>
```

The actual result that I am getting is

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<FileRecord>
   <HeaderRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </HeaderRecord>
   <SectionRecord Subject="Science">
      <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Physics">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Chemistry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Biology">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
   </SectionRecord>
   <SectionRecord Subject="Math">
      <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionHeader>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Geometry">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Algebra">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Calculus">
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileA</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
   </SectionRecord>
   <SectionRecord Subject="History">
      <SectionHeader>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionHeader>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Ancient">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionDetails Stream="Modern">
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionDetails>
      <SectionTrailer>
            <A>FileB</A>
        </SectionTrailer>
   </SectionRecord>
   <TrailerRecord>
        <A>FileA</A>
    </TrailerRecord>
</FileRecord>
```

In the Section Subject=Science, the ordering of Physics, Chemistry and Biology came out correct, but I want FileA record to appear before FileB Record. In the Section record for Math, Geometry showed up before Algebra and Calculus. I want it to appear in the order of FileA (and FileA record to appear before FileB record). Why did it mess up the ordering on the Math but not on Science?

Also I don't like the use of hard coded number to access the first file records
`<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/SectionHeader"/>`

Is there a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
         <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()//SectionDetails" group-by="@Stream">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
```

to

```
         <xsl:for-each-group select="for $rec in current-group() return $rec/SectionDetails" group-by="@Stream">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Using a `for return` expression should preserve the order of the outer population when you deal with nodes from different documents while it is undefined and unpredictable if you use `current-group()//SectionDetails`.

As for simplifying `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/SectionHeader"/>`, inside of a `for-each-group` the first item in each group is the context item so instead of `current-group()[1]` you can simply use `.` e.g. `./SectionHeader` which of course can be shortened to `SectionHeader` i.e. `<xsl:apply-templates select="SectionHeader"/>`

Not sure however why you use XSLT 2 constructs like `for-each-group` and in the comment to the other answer then mention Xalan which, being an XSLT 1 processor, does not support `for-each-group`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Honnen.This one worked exactly as I wanted it to. Do you have a recommendation on how do I refer to the first file for sectionDetails? Right now I have hard coded [1]. Is there a better way.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to use `sectionDetails[1]` in your code so I am not sure what your additional question in the comment is about. Ask a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: When I select the first element from currentGroup - current-group()[1]/SectionHeader

Comment: The penultimate paragraph in the answer already has a suggestion to shorten `current-group()[1]/SectionHeader` to `./SectionHeader` respectively `SectionHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reproduce your error, but my output matched your desired outcome.

Use `FileA.xml` as the first input file:

```
transform.xslt FileA.xml
```

and `FileB.xml` as the second input file in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:param name="filebrecs" select="document('FileB.xml')"/>
```

Then your output will be as expected.

Comment: If I switch, the Header and Trailer come from FileB. I want them to come from FileA. In my actual FileA has ~ 30000 records and FileB has ~500 records. So I don't want to switch these files

Comment: I checked it and with Saxon-9HE the `Header` and the `Trailer` do come from `FileA` with `java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:transform.xslt FileA.xml`. I updated my answer.

Comment: That's strange. I double checked the calls and even the code and `FileA.xml` should be the source of the `HeaderRecord` children. The line `<xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderRecord"/>` should copy the children of the `FileA.xml` elements.

Comment: Yes. I run it with `FileA.xml`, because the document included with `document('FileB.xml')` is `FileB.xml`.

Comment: You changed the answer so my first comment doesn't make sense anymore. I ran it with Saxon and I still have the same issue. FileB record show before FileA records and whenever there is a match, the whole group gets to the top of the Section.

Comment: Also, I am looking for an answer that will let me control this ordering and not leave it to implementation (saxon vs xalan). Unfortunately I can't use saxon in Prod. I am stuck with xalan

Comment: I'm maybe as unsatisfied as you are. I get the correct outcome here, but I cannot commit it to you. I doubt that the XSLT processor is of importance in this case.

Comment: If you call the stylesheet with `FileA.xml` as the document to be processed, the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="HeaderRecord"/>` should copy the data from it (FileA.xml).